# Image Processing with AForge: Empty Array?

Tags: c#, image, image-processing, indexoutofboundsexception, aforge

I am fairly new to image processing, and I recently found the AForge library. I have been attempting a basic comparison between 2 images and I want it to return the percentage of similarity between them. However, I am constantly getting an Index Out of Bounds exception as the result of having an empty array, but I am unsure of why `ex.ProcessImage` is returning an empty array. I pretty much replicated the example code provided in the documentation, yet I am still having an error. Here is my code:

```
static class Run
{
    public static void go()
    {
        string filename1 = null;
        string filename2 = null;

        filename1 = "a.a.jpg";
        filename2 = "b.b.jpg";

        Bitmap image1 = new Bitmap(filename1);
        Bitmap image2 = new Bitmap(filename2);

        ExhaustiveTemplateMatching ex = new ExhaustiveTemplateMatching( 0 );
        TemplateMatch[] match  = ex.ProcessImage (image1, image2);

        float similarity = match[0].Similarity; //where the error occurs

        Console.WriteLine("They are" + similarity + "% similar.");
    }
}
```

The only thing that I can imagine it being would be how I am doing my bitmaps. But, I do believe I did those correctly. I also have tried other ways of initialising the bitmaps, and I still receive the same error.

It's probably some stupid mistake that I am just not realising, but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I never managed to figure out what was causing this issue, but I created a new project with the exact same code and it worked. So, this question no longer needs to be answered.

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting an `IndexOutOfRangeException`, that suggests that `ex.ProcessImage` has returned an empty array. The next thing to do is work out why. Presumably there are no template matches...

As an aside, this code is pointlessly longwinded:

```
string filename1 = null;
string filename2 = null;

filename1 = "a.a.jpg";
filename2 = "b.b.jpg";
```

It would be shorter and clearer as:

```
string filename1 = "a.a.jpg";
string filename2 = "b.b.jpg";
```

Comment: I did that because I originally had it where I would type in the file names, and then removed it. The "why" is what I'm trying to figure out.

Comment: @NathanPrice: Then really your question isn't about an IndexOutOfBoundsException - it's "why is ExhaustiveTemplateMatching returning an empty array".

Comment: Alright, sorry that my question was incorrect for what I was looking for. I'll edit it now to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

Save the images as .bmp and try again.

```
 string filename1 = "a.a.bmp";
 string filename2 = "b.b.bmp";
```